# .net 7 console app randomly terminates without any error message

Tags: .net, console

I have an odd issue that I have a .NET 7 Console App that terminates in random places without giving any error message! I had the same issue when it was running in .NET 6.

It does the same thing whether a debugger is attached or not and I have also tested in both VS and VSCode, again the same behavior so is very odd.

I have never seen this type of behavior in all my years as a .net dev, you normally always get an error message and line number! It just terminates with the message:

"NextGenSoftware.Holochain.HoloNET.Client.TestHarness.exe (process 31752) exited with code 0."

Which really doesn't help me, be nice if I was given a clue what the error is?! lol

It doesn't have any unmanaged code, it is a .net/unity client for holochain and talks to the conductor/exe (written in rust) via websocket using messagepack to encode messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!